# Is it possible to specify the time zone on Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, azure, timezone

I am going to migrating a system to Windows Azure. And it will used UTC time for all existing function. Is there any way to set the time zone globally? Or I need to change all the code which display the time? My application will mainly serve in a specified timezone.

I have try apply the culture and uiculture on web.config. And it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Windows Azure Team Blog - all the timing calculations/display etc have been moved to UTC.. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/moving-to-coordinated-universal-time-utc/

I feel you would need to change the code which display the time as well which saves the time as well..

Comment: Besides, the timezone is something that belongs to the user's profile, not a global setting.