# New Azure site following UTC time zone change our flow in our sytem

Tags: c#, azure

Please Help. Any suggestions are welcome. Willing to make a small donation for any correct, and holding my hand through this crisis.

1st, It all started where, We were using a Dedicated server that used Eastern Time Zone to save events in this structure:

```
public class Event
{
DateTime StartTime {get;set;}
DateTime EndTime {get;set;}
}
```

Then a user would select a time and date (From eastern time) and post to our server like so:

```
public Save(DateTime start,DateTime end)
{
    //I now save it to UTC time, Why save it as UTC idk, I was told it was the best way to save //time and dates in c#
    var newEvent = new Event{StartTime = start.ToUniversalTime() ,EndTime=end.ToUniversalTime()};
    _dependcyInjector.Save(newEvent);
}
```

Simple enough right? So lets review so far. We have an event object. From a website, a user would post off the new Date and time in Eastern Time, and we would save it in universal time.

Ok now here is where things are starting to hit the Fan. We moved everything from a Dedicated server on EST to a Azure site which is UTC based. So now all of the events that are saving off is different meaning that they are not saving in what I thought would be universal time when I call start.UniversalTime(). And now what even makes it even worse, we have services that Kicks off events that are now broken for example:

```
public void KickoffEvents()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //This use to work perfectly, now it doesnt because of the Azure server time, I am not even //sure what time its try to compare it to anymore. 
    var events = (from x in Events where x.StartTime < now select x).ToList(); 
    MoveEvents(events[0]);//Just example
}
```

So the big issue, I would need help with is:

1. Saving time, we would like the UI to be eastern time based if possible, but then how should I save the time? Convert to Universal? Save eastern?
2. Pulling out the time Utc.Now does not work anymore. What should I do?

I looked into TimeDateOffset, but I simply got confused. Please any help would be much appreciated, we have our first event coming up next week and I am totally lost.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow should be the exact same value (within some small deviation) across all computers around the globe provided they are set to the correct local time and have a complete and up-to-date DST database.  I would trust Azure servers to be correct in this matter.

Comment: Second, you save time in UTC because UTC doesn't participate in daylight savings - so conversion to/from timezones is much easier, and your data is consistent.  Imagine storing times from across the globe and then trying to query for all events that took place between 5am and 6am.  *nightmare*

Comment: Can you please provide an example @Dan-o?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the ToUniversalTime() method of your "start" and "end" DateTime objects, the method converts the time from local time into UTC (Assuming the DateTime.Kind is set to Unspecified, which it is in this case). So, before you switched servers, it worked because the timezone of the server happened to be the same as the timezone you wanted to convert from.

However, now the timezone of your server has changed so you will have to switch timezones in a different way when saving your DateTime objects. Try this

```
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var newEvent = new Event{StartTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(start, tzInfo)
                        ,EndTime=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(end, tzInfo)};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660586/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-time-zone-on-windows-azure?rq=1):

> As per the Windows Azure Team Blog - all the timing
>   calculations/display etc have been moved to UTC.
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/moving-to-coordinated-universal-time-utc/

Which means that you need to convert from UTC to EST for display:

```
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

and back again for saving.

Comment: I am already posting EST time from the website. Do I need to not touch what the site posted, how do I compare now time to what is saved? I kinda need more details, what you provided is not clear.

Comment: I would need to know like. Step 1, When you are saving you need to save like...... Step 2. When you are comparing Time you need to.......

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saving the event?

- logging to a database?
- writing to a file?
- adding to a queue?

On the server, what do the dates look like vs. what you want them to look like. Give examples.

Can you confirm dates on the Azure server are 5:00 ahead of EST? We are not in daylight savings time now so 5:00 is the right number.

Did you read the answer that I posted yesterday?
I'm in Florida BTW. To get your system right you may need to decide on a strategy and then update all of your old dates so that everything is normal again. I'll help you out if I can.

I've never used Azure. I know it's a big shared server farm kind of thing. Do they give you terminal access or is it web-based? Try calling `TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;`. I would expect it to return 00:00:00 if the server is configured for UTC time.